# how to change the background of Buefy's Select?

Tags: bulma, buefy

I'm a beginner coder and I started to work with Bulma and Buefy for 2 weeks, and I've been struggling to change this select's background color => [Select Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp0wJ.png), I already tried things like

```
.select select{
background color : red;
}
```

And

```
select{
background color : red;
}
```

but without success, can someone help me with that?

My code below:

```
      <div class="selectItem">
        <span>Ship to End User</span>
        <b-select placeholder="Ship to End User" size="is-small">
          <option value="Test">Test</option>
        </b-select>
      </div>
```

REMARKS :
I'm using Bulma and Buefy so Sass is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your Sass file, you can indicate the custom color for the input fields (including select) like this:

`$input-background-color: red;`

Reference: https://bulma.io/documentation/form/input/#variables

- If you want to change only the background color of the select elements, instead of modifying Sass file, you can use this CSS config:

```
<style>
span.select.is-large > select {
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```